# Footer using Flexbox

Tags: flexbox

I have an issue when trying to make a footer using flexbox.  I want the footer to appear at the bottom of the webpage using `align-items: flex-end`. I found an answer on this website saying that I need to add 100% height to my code, but when I do it adds more than the height of the screen and makes it so I need to scroll to see the footer.  Here is the basis of what I'm doing (I made the whole footer green so I could see what was happening):

http://jsfiddle.net/kk4jec81/2/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you wanting the footer to stay stuck to the bottom? If so, do you want the content to push it away as the page fills up (requiring you to scroll down in order to see the footer), or do you want the footer to ALWAYS be stuck at the bottom (so that it's visible no matter how much content you have on your page)?

Comment: I've just been playing around with what you created... and while I don't think it's what you're looking for just yet, I think there might be some stuff that will help you. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/kk4jec81/3/) Let me know exactly what you're looking for, and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked but here's a way to solve it:
http://jsfiddle.net/kk4jec81/9/

I added some comments on the CSS but what I did is `body {display:flex;flex-flow:column;}`, then I deleted the 100% of the footer and finally `.menuContainer {margin-top:auto;}`.

Hope that helps.